# Why is my bootstrap navbar collapsed at any screen size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar partial in views/layouts in Rails app. It is always in this collapsed state, and not even in the right form of collapsing. What am I doing wrong with the code?

https://january-app.herokuapp.com/users

Updated the version syntax with a little bit success. Still doesn't work right though.

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 3 Component syntax, but you are loading Bootstrap 4 alpha. Just use the following [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#content) page.

Comment: Thank you David. I didn't realize that. Good to know!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add navbar in your , so correct version will be , please check it below, an vote right answer please

```
<div class="navbar navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>
```